# Solr multiple split

Tags: solr

I have this field "posts" in my mysql table with this kind of string (key=value, delimited by comma) :

```
P5=6,P15=3,P26=1
```

In SOLR, I'd like to be able to index each 'P*' as dynamic fields with their corresponding value so I can query them and return them as facets.

This is the end result I'm looking for :

```
    'response'=>array(
    'P5'=>'6',
    'P15'=>'3',
    'P26'=>1,
     ...
```

Beside using splitBy="," to separate the key/value pairs, I don't know what to do next.

```
<field column="postes" name="postes" splitBy=","/>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a dynamic field name as `P_*`

```
<dynamicField name="P_*" type="string"/>
```

And then you have to pass the data by converting the array to key value pairs.

If you have original data as below.

```
P5=6,P15=3,P26=1
```

the you should covert it to separate rows as below and push to Solr.

```
P5=6
P15=3
P26=1
```